# How do you measure performance for word prediction tasks?

Tags: nlp, metric

Say I have to predict the next word in a sentence, given the initial few words.

Suppose the prefix is "I went to _____". This prefix is common enough that it might appear 10 times in the training data with a few different variations:

I went to **college**: 5

I went to **California**: 3

I went to **London**: 2

In such a case, suppose my model predicts "college" as the right answer. It would still get only a 50% score if I used accuracy as a metric, the data naturally has multiple (correct) answers for the same input. How do I solve this?

Comment: From my understanding using this "metrics =['accuracy']" is not a very good measure of the model performance especially word prediction models.it just gives you a rough idea of what's actually going on with your model.

Answer (score 1):

After 4 years and much more experience with Machine Learning (I started a full-time career in the field) I think I have a better idea of the answer.

Prediction accuracy can be used here, but as mentioned by @mucho, it's not the best for data which naturally have multiple categorical answers. Here, the ground-truth is a probability distribution.

If our task is to perfectly mimic this distribution, we should use a metric which compares probability distributions, such as Cross-Entropy (which is mathematically equivalent to KL Divergence).

If our objective is to get a good language model, there are other ways. A popular objective since 2018 is Masked Language Modeling (a Cloze task) which is employed by the BERT architecture l

Answer (score 0):

Your accuracy should be this: Did the phrase existed before? It means either storing all combinations of 4-grams or searching the data on the fly.

But then the prediction algorithm that uses any combination from the previous data will be 100% accurate. I do not really understand the reason for such accuracy estimation.

Answer (score 0):

Take this with a grain of salt (I'm super new to this stuff), and I'm assuming this is only a piece to the puzzle, but maybe someone with more expertise can build on this.  I wonder, though, if utilizing a [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) to quantify the accuracy of the string would be helpful.  I got some pretty accurate correlations from a previous project, though I've admittedly never used it for NLP.  If this is a terrible idea, I'd be interested to know why...